# A kind of Grönwall's inequality in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Consider an initival value problem
$$\dot x = f(x), x \in \mathbb R^n, x(0) = x_0$$
Suppose $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous with a constant $L$.
I'd like to find a lower and an upper bound on $\| x(t) \|$ in terms of $x_0$ and $L$. In scalar case, Grönwall's inequality would work.
Is this derivation right?
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\|x\| = \frac{x^{\top} \dot x}{\|x\|} \le \| \dot x \| \le \| x_0 \| e^{Lt} $$
It seems right unless $\|x\| \ne 0$. It is true in general? Does there exist a "symmetric" lower bound of the type
$$ \| x(t) \| \ge \|x_0\|(2 - e^{Lt})$$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use
$$
\|\dot x\|\le \|f(x_0)\|+\|f(x)-f(x_0)\|=K+L\|x-x_0\|
$$
to find
$$
\|x-x_0\|\le \frac{K}{L}(e^{Lt}-1)
$$

---

You get this inequality for instance by computing
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ln(K+L·\|x(t)-x_0\|)\le\frac{L·\|\dot x\|}{K+L·\|x(t)-x_0\|}\le L
\\\implies 
K+L·\|x(t)-x_0\|\le e^{Lt}·K.
$$
Note that due to the triangle inequality 
$$\bigl|\|x(t)\|-\|x_0\|\bigr|\le \|x(t)-x_0\|$$
this already provides a two-sided bound for $\|x(t)\|$.

Comment: It seems to me you treated derivative as if it were outside the norm. Why?

Comment: Set $\phi(t)=\|x(t)-x_0\|$, then $\phi'(t)\le\|x'(t)\|\le K+L\phi(t)$. Then consider $\frac{d}{dt}\ln(K+L\phi(t))\le L$ which implies $ K+L\phi(t)\le Ke^{Lt}$.

Comment: This includes a lower bound as $$\|x_0\|-\|x(t)-x_0\|\le \|x(t)\|\le\|x_0\|+\|x(t)-x_0\|.$$ For a bound that moves it away from the constant solution you would need a lower bound on the slope of $f$, for instance per a Lipschitz constant on $f^{-1}$, if the inverse function exists.